# How to expand Box Composable by toggleSwitch(Android , Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing on dividing the composable in the box in the form of a column using Jetpack composable. I would like to know if other composable are affected by the size of the composable in the box and can be resized automatically. 
The shape of the calendar changes according to the change of the custom toggle Switch in TopAppBar. According to the shape of the calendar, I would like to change the size of the box's Row-type text under the calendar, such as being pulled and pushed.
How can i fix it?

**Code:**

```
val states = listOf("월간", "주간")
    var selectedOption by remember { mutableStateOf(states[0]) }

    val onSelectionChange = { text: String -> selectedOption = text }

    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .width(115.dp)
                    .height(35.dp)
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                    .background(Color(0xffe9e9ed))
                    .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 5.dp, top = 6.dp, bottom = 5.dp)) {
                    states.forEach { text ->
                        Text(text = text,
                            fontSize = 10.sp,
                            lineHeight = 16.sp,
                            color = if (text == selectedOption) {
                                Color.Black
                            } else {
                                Color.Gray
                            },
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
                                .clickable {
                                    onSelectionChange(text)
                                    isVisible = (text == states[1])
//                                            isVisible = !isVisible
                                }
                                .background(if (text == selectedOption) {
                                    Color.White
                                } else {
                                    Color(0xffe9e9ed)
                                })
                                .padding(
                                    vertical = 5.dp,
                                    horizontal = 16.dp,
                                ))
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    goDetailProfile(NAV_ROUTE.PROFILE, routeAction)
                }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "profile")
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = Color.White,
                titleContentColor = Color.Black))
    }) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xfff0f0f0))) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f),
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 30.dp, bottomEnd = 30.dp))) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        Kalendar(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(top = 45.dp)
                                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 30.dp,
                                    bottomEnd = 30.dp)),
                            kalendarHeaderConfig = KalendarHeaderConfig(
                                kalendarTextConfig = KalendarTextConfig(
                                    kalendarTextColor = KalendarTextColor(Color.Black),
                                    kalendarTextSize = KalendarTextSize.SubTitle)
                            ),
//                            kalendarEvents = List<KalendarDay> (
//                                size = ,
//                                init =
//                                    ),
                            kalendarType = KalendarType.Oceanic(),
                            kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                            kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(backgroundColor = Color.White,
                                dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                                headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                            onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                                year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                                month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                                day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth

                                readTodo(token, year, month, day, response = {

                                    todoList.clear()
                                    for (i in it!!.data) {
                                        todoList.add(i)
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                    } else {
                        Kalendar(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(top = 25.dp)
                                .clip(
                                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                                        bottomStart = 30.dp,
                                        bottomEnd = 30.dp)),
                            kalendarHeaderConfig = KalendarHeaderConfig(kalendarTextConfig = KalendarTextConfig(
                                kalendarTextColor = KalendarTextColor(Color.Black),
                                kalendarTextSize = KalendarTextSize.SubTitle)),
//                            com.himanshoe.kalendar.component.day.KalendarDay(kalendarDay =,
//                                selectedKalendarDay =,
//                                kalendarDayColors =,
//                                dotColor =,
//                                dayBackgroundColor =),
//                            kalendarEvents = List<KalendarEvent>(
//
//                            ),
                            kalendarType = KalendarType.Firey,
                            kalendarDayColors = KalendarDayColors(Color.Black, Color.Black),
                            kalendarThemeColor = KalendarThemeColor(backgroundColor = Color.White,
                                dayBackgroundColor = Color(0xffFBE3C7),
                                headerTextColor = Color.Black),
                            onCurrentDayClick = { kalendarDay: KalendarDay, kalendarEvents: List<KalendarEvent> ->

                                year = kalendarDay.localDate.year
                                month = kalendarDay.localDate.monthNumber
                                day = kalendarDay.localDate.dayOfMonth

                                readTodo(token, year, month, day, response = {

                                    todoList.clear()
                                    for (i in it!!.data) {
                                        todoList.add(i)
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                    }
                }
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .padding(top = 30.dp)
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 21.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = day.toString(),
                            fontSize = 26.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 5.dp)
                        )

                        Divider(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(start = 5.dp),
                            color = Color(0xffD8D8D8)
                        )
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(top = 50.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
                    ) {
                        TodoItemList(Todo = todoList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am developing a calendar app in Jetpack Compose, and I am using the `Column` composable to structure the UI. First, I compose either the `MonthView` or the `WeekView`, and then I compose the `TasksList`. By doing this, when the user toggles between the `MonthView` and the `WeekView`, the TasksList is automatically adjusted by the Column layout.

```
@Composable
fun MyCalendar() {

    Column {
        if (isMonthView) {
            MonthView()
        } else {
            WeekView()
        }
        TasksList()
    }
}
```

Comment: thx to advise! how can u develop toogles abt Jetpack Compose?

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: yes, i made a toggleSwitch to custom. here is my code.https://gist.github.com/ParkJongJoon7128/23b3813cbc33b3b6f186c0018dc25339
I want to know how to code more effectively.